# Error al instalar el paquete autocomplete-python en Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Estaba intentando instalar los paquetes para empezar a usar el entorno Atom. Cuando creo un archivo .py y escribo cualquier cosa en él me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando utilizo la consola del Windows solo ejecuta el python con el comando py.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que ese es el problema pero no sé como corregirlo en el paquete.

Agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: pues lo que yo hice fue ejecutar pip install 'python-lenguage-server [all]' desde la atom, en la consola... tal vez eso arregle tu problema

Comment: 2 cosas: a. ¿Ya instalaste el interprete de Python? Si no, [aquí](https://www.python.org/downloads/) b. Ya definiste al `bin` de Python como variable de entorno? Por lo visto tu SO es Win10, [esto te puede servir](https://medium.com/@01luisrene/como-agregar-variables-de-entorno-s-o-windows-10-e7f38851f11f). Espero que te ayude, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el mismo error al momento de utilizar python en atom sin embargo buscando entre foros encontre el siguiente comando que resolvio el problema:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade flake8 --user
```

Espero te funcione al igual que a mi